# Como verificar se um item está contido em um array?

Tags: javascript, array, if

O que estou fazendo errado nesse `if`?

```
if (angular.uppercase(nome[id]) in ['A', 'E','I', 'O', 'U']) {
    ....
}
```

Se eu fizer somente assim funciona. Mas vou ter que repetir para os outros.

```
if (angular.uppercase(nome[id]) == 'A'){
    .....
}
```

Estou usando esse código dentro do meu *controller*.

```
$scope.verificaVogal = function(nome) {
  var dados = {};
  for (id = 0; id < nome.length; id++) {
    if (angular.uppercase(nome[id]) in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']) {
      dados[id] = 'é vogal';
    } else {
      dados[id] = 'não é vogal';
    }
  }
  return dados;
}
```

Agradeço pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está utilizando o operador `in` incorretamente, a função dele é retornar `true` se a propriedade especificada estiver no objeto especificado. No seu caso você está trabalhando com um *array* e não um objeto.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

Fonte: [in operator (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Para verificar se um item está contido num *array*, que parece ter sido a sua intenção, será necessário utilizar o método [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) da seguinte forma:

```
if (['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'].indexOf(angular.uppercase(nome[id])) != -1) {
    dados[id] = 'é vogal';
} else {
    dados[id] = 'não é vogal';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Zignd!!!

Answer (score 4):

Tente fazer assim:

```
$scope.verificaVogal = function(nome) {
  var dados = {};
  for (id = 0; id < nome.length; id++) {
    if (angular.uppercase(nome[id]) in {'A':'', 'E':'', 'I':'', 'O':'', 'U':''}) {
      dados[id] = 'é vogal';
    } else {
      dados[id] = 'não é vogal';
    }
  }
  return dados;
}
```

Fica um pouco "feio" desse modo, mas é funcional. Teste no seu código.

O operador `in` do javascript é utilizado para a verificação de chaves em **objetos** e no seu caso você possui um *array*.

Uma verificação em `arrays` é realmente feita da maneira que o @Zignd falou. Mas você também pode transformar as matrizes (arrays) em objetos com a seguinte função:

```
function toObject(array){
  var object = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    object[array[i]]='';
  }
  return object;
}
```

Com isso, basta fazer assim:

```
if (angular.uppercase(nome[id]) in toObject(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'])) {
  dados[id] = 'é vogal';
} else {
  dados[id] = 'não é vogal';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Samir Braga!!!

Answer (score 4):

Já foi dito a maior parte nas outras respostas. Deixo uma outra resposta com algumas coisas ainda não ditas.

Nota que quando usas `for (id = 0; id` estás a declarar essa variável globalmente e podes estar a sobrescrever valores nas outras variáveis que possam ter o mesmo nome. Junta sempre `var` em `for (var i = ...`.

No teu código estás a criar um objeto com index numerário. Nesse caso vais ter algo como

```
{
    0: 'string',
    1: 'outra string',
    etc...
```

e sendo assim parece-me mais semântico (ie mais correto) mapear a string inicial.  Deixo também uma sugestão com regex, que dispensa o `.indexOf` e `uppercase`.

Nesse caso o código que queres poderia ser assim:

```
$scope.verificaVogal = function(nome) {
    var vogais = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
    return nome.split('').map(function(letra) {
        return vogais.indexOf(angular.uppercase(letra) != -1);
    });
}
```

ou assim:

```
$scope.verificaVogal = function(nome) {
    return nome.match(/[aeiou]/i);
}
```

Nota: se usares a primeira variante, eu prefiro assim:

```
(function(){
    var vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    $scope.verificaVogal = function(nome) {
        return nome.split('').map(function(letra) {
                return vogais.indexOf(letra.toLowerCase()) != -1);
        });
    }
})();
```

para diminuir sempre que possível código não nativo e para não declarar constantes dentro da função.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sergio!!!